# Kill Thread Explicitly in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have C# Code where I am invoking SAP BAPI, but sometime it takes too long to get a response back.

I can only wait for 3 seconds to get a response back. If it's does not return in 3 seconds, then I would like to terminate the call and continue with the next line.

```
funcArtike2.SetValue("CLI", CLI);             
funcArtike2.Invoke(rfcDest);

string CA = funcArtike2["CONTRACT_ACCOUNT"].GetValue().ToString().Trim() != "".ToString() ? funcArtike2["CONTRACT_ACCOUNT"].GetValue().ToString().Trim() : "X";
//IRfcStructure RETURN = funcArtike2["RETURN"].GetStructure();
string BP = funcArtike2["BUSINESS_PARTNER"].ToString().Substring(funcArtike2["BUSINESS_PARTNER"].ToString().IndexOf("=")+1);
```

`funcArtike2.Invoke(rfcDest);` is the statement I want to skip after waiting for 3 seconds.

Comment: `Thread.Abort()` ?

Comment: @J3soon [What's wrong with using `Thread.Abort()`?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1559255/447156)

Comment: Can you please help me with a sample code.? I mean where to implement Thread.Abort()

Comment: @SonerGönül, you're absolutely right, the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.abort(v=vs.110).aspx) has a warning about this.

Comment: You need to abort the whole method, if `funcArtike2.Invoke(rfcDest);` takes more than 3 sec?

Comment: Or just skip to the next line?

Comment: I mean Abort and continue to the next line.

Comment: @SonerGönül: The funny thing is that *everything* is wrong with Thread.Abort, starting with its name. There is no guarantee that calling Thread.Abort ever aborts the thread.

Comment: Do you really need to terminate the call or are you happy to simply move on and let it run its course in the background?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
AutoResetEvent signal = new AutoResetEvent(false);
Timer timer = new Timer(3000);
timer.Elapsed += (sender, e) => signal.Set();        

funcArtike2.SetValue("CLI", CLI);

Thread thread = new Thread(()=>{
            funcArtike2.Invoke(rfcDest);
            signal.Set();
        });

thread.Start(); //start the function thread
timer.Start(); //start the timer

signal.WaitOne(); //waits for either the timer to elapse or the task to complete

string CA = funcArtike2["CONTRACT_ACCOUNT"].GetValue().ToString().Trim() != "".ToString() ? funcArtike2["CONTRACT_ACCOUNT"].GetValue().ToString().Trim() : "X";
            //IRfcStructure RETURN = funcArtike2["RETURN"].GetStructure();
string BP = funcArtike2["BUSINESS_PARTNER"].ToString().Substring(funcArtike2["BUSINESS_PARTNER"].ToString().IndexOf("=")+1);
```

We assume that the call:

```
funcArtike2.Invoke(rfcDest);
```

is synchronous, otherwise it will not work.

Note also that this will not kill the funcArtike2.Invoke(rfcDest) method call, just ignore it and move on. So if you start any expensive operations (e.g. DB call, file, IO, heavy computation), bad luck since you need to take care of that yourself.

Comment: I am using Web Service .Net 4.0.  Task.Run() is not supported in .Net 4.0 can you please help me with Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ?

Comment: I'll handle this, signal.Set(), signal.WaitOne(), I didn't find them anywhere. Please help

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I am aborting the thread after 3 seconds, and using **AutoResetEvent** class instead of signal.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I forgot. Updating it now.

Answer (score -1):

```
var response = expectedResponse;
var timer = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();
while(timer.ElapsedMilliseconds < 3001)
{
     //Evaluate to see if you have received the response.
     if(response != null) { funcArtike2.Invoke(rfcDest); break; }
     if(timer.ElapsedMilliseconds == 3000) { throw new TimeoutException("Response was not received within three seconds."); 
}
// Handle the exception down here.
```

If you do not need the response to continue your work then remove the exception and have your code continue below the loop.

Comment: No the best solution since it will call, DoWork() a lot of times.

Comment: This is just an illustration, the OP can manipulate it to fit his required business logic. For instance, DoWork() could check the input parameter for a null value and break if a response has been received. Use your imagination.;)

Comment: It's a pretty bad illustration since it will wait in all cases 3 seconds, even if the function call will take less.